# How to upload pie file successfully in GraphDB by ontotext

Tags: hidden-field, graphdb

I have the pie file which is used for inference in GraphDB ontotext. I have written the ruleset correctly. while uploading the file it seems ok. But, while creating the repository, it is showing the “Invalid Ruleset file. Please upload valid one” I think the issue is related to the hidden character present inside the file. How to get out if such characters. My file content is :

```
Prefices
{
rdf : http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
owl : http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#
abc : http://www.xyzabc.com/schema/abcentity#
}

Axioms
{
<abc:isLocatedIn> <rdf:type> <owl:ObjectProperty>
}

Rules
{

Id: isLocatedInHierarchy

a <abc:isLocatedIn> b [Constraint a != b]
b <abc:isLocatedIn> c [Constraint b != c]
```

---

```
a <abc:isLocatedIn> c [Constraint a != c]
```

}

Comment: The PIE file looks correct. 
I was able to create a repository using it (copy/paste from the question) and only replaced the delimiter between the head and the consequent part of the rule with a line of several 'dash' characters, like '--------'

Answer (score 1):

> hidden character present inside the file

Do you mean a Unicode BOM mark? Get an editor that can save without such mark (I strongly recommend Akelpad: http://akelpad.sourceforge.net/), or just save in ASCII.

BTW, writing PIE files with per-property rules is not a good idea. Instead, use a generic rule for transitive property and then declare `abc:isLocatedIn` transitive in your ontology. The cheapest builtin in which such rule is included is `rdfsPlus-optimized`. If you select it, then you add to your ontology

```
abc:isLocatedIn a owl:TransitiveProperty.
```

However, it's a better idea to keep a "step" property `abc:isLocatedIn` and then a transitive property on top of it, eg `abc:isLocatedTransitive`:

```
abc:isLocatedTransitive a owl:TransitiveProperty.
abc:isLocatedIn rdfs:subPropertyOf abc:isLocatedTransitive.
```

Finally, there's a more efficient way to compute the transitive closure, see http://rawgit2.com/VladimirAlexiev/my/master/pubs/extending-owl2/index.html#sec-3-1:

```
abc:isLocatedTransitive ptop:transitiveOver abc:isLocatedIn.
abc:isLocatedIn rdfs:subPropertyOf abc:isLocatedTransitive.
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was also been able to upload successfully your .pie file. Maybe the issue is related to the computer locale or something in the environment. If you are using Windows Notepad++ seems like a logical choice. I guess there is an option to view all the hidden characters, but I've never used it. If you are using Linux there are plenty of choices, even included one like vim or nano which will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin :)